# Is there a right identity for Application in Lambda calculus?

Tags: applications, lambda-calculus

Such a function `E` that:

```
∀F (F E = F)
```

It's obviously, that the left identity `E' (E' F = F)` is a function `(λx.x)`. Indeed: `(λx.x) F == F`.

But is there a right one like that?

Or is there evidence that such an element does not exist?

In common case, is there a chain of elements `(E1 E2 … En)` for every well-formed expression (function) of Lambda calculus which fulfills the condition:

```
∀F (F E1 E2 … En = F) (n >=1)
```

Is there a method to build such a chain?

PS For **some** functions it is easy, for example:

```
Let F := (λa.λb.a b), then E1 := (λс.c) and E2 := F:
(λa.λb.a b) (λс.c) (λa.λb.a b) =>β 
(λb.(λс.c) b) (λa.λb.a b) =>β 
(λb.b) (λa.λb.a b) =>α 
(λb.b) (λa.λc.a c) =>β 
λa.λc.a c) =>α 
(λa.λb.a b)
```

but what about, for example `(λa.λb.a b a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the answer is definitely **no** - at least, in any reasonable context.

The short version: think about any constant map $\lambda x.p$, and what the existence of a right identity says about this map.

---

In more detail:

*For simplicity I'll play a bit fast and loose with the details below.*

I'll take as my context an arbitrary [partial applicative structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra) $(A,\cdot)$. First, suppose our PAS is *total*. A reasonable requirement is for *constant maps* to exist: for each $a\in A$ there should be some $c_a\in A$ with $c_ax=a$ for all $x\in A$. We now have a problem. If each element $x$ of $A$ has a right identity $e_x$, then we must have $$c_ae_{c_a}=c_a$$ for each $a\in A$. But $c_ae_{c_a}=a$ for each $a\in A$, so we get $$a=c_a$$ for every $a\in A$. We are thus in the degenerate situation where **every functional is constant**.

So total PASs don't  have right identities unless they're extremely trivial, and in particular there is exactly one *(fine, up to isomorphism)* PAS of a given cardinality which has right identities. But essentially the same problem happens even if we drop totality. Call an element $a\in A$ *almost constant* if there is some $v_a$ such that $ab=v_a$ whenever $ab$ is defined. Then - yet again - a right fixed point $c$ for $a$ must make $ac$ defined, and so we get $ac=v_a=a$. In particular, for each $v$ there is *at most one* functional in $A$ which is only ever $v$ when defined, and that element is $v$ itself. At this point the mere existence of a "nearly constant" map for an arbitrary $v\in A$ collapses everything yet again: an element $a$ of $A$ is characterized completely by the subset $D_a$ of $A$ on which it is defined, and for each $d\in D_a$ we have $ad=a$. This does give more variety than the total case, but not *much* more, and in particular I think any reasonable semantics for anything like $\lambda$-calculus will not be satisfied by such a thing.

And in particular, no nontrivial **partial combinatory algebra** - and these are to my understanding the "best" PASs - can have this property. First, note that for each $a$ the object $Ka$ is equal to $a$ on all inputs (that is, $Kab=a$ for all $b$); by the above, this means $Ka=a$. In particular, since $Ka$ is total we get that each $a\in A$ behaves as the constant function $\lambda x.a$. In particular, *our algebra is total*. But now consider the $S$-object. By the above we have $Sa=S$ for every $a$. However, by the above we also know that $(ac)(bc)=ab=a$ for all $a,b,c\in A$; the $S$-axiom then tells us that $Sabc=(ac)(bc)=a$ for all $a,b,c\in A$. But $Sabc=((Sa)b)c=S$, and so we get $a=S$ - that is, **our PCA has only one element**.

Comment: @Noah_Schweber Thank you very much
!